# Passing contents of a file on the command line

Tags: bash, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to figure out how I can send arguments (which are contents in a file) on the command line as parameters to a cpp function. I am NOT trying to send it through stdin.

I have a function named foo.cpp:

```
  $ cat foo.cpp
  #include <iostream>
  int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
      for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
          std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
      return 0;
  }
  $ g++ -o foo foo.cpp
  $ ./foo hello world
  hello
  world
```

In the last command executed, I'm passing the arguments "hello world" into the program. However, what if I have "hello world" in a file? For example:

```
 $ cat footest.args
 $ hello world
```

How would I pass the contents of footest.args into ./foo as above?
I've tried

```
  ./foo | cat footest.args
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You want to take output of a command and transform it into arguments. Try command substitution:

```
./foo $(< footest.args)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with:

```
cat footest.arg | xargs ./foo
```

or (thanks to @glenn)

```
xargs ./foo < footest.arg
```

avoiding one unnecessary use of `cat`.

Comment: or `xargs ./foo < footest.arg`